# <XSD:any> issue in version 1.0

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to write a schema for an xml which has basically two nodes.

```
  <FirstData>
       <First name="name1" value="value1"/>
       <Second name="name1" value="value1"/>
       <Third name="name1" value="value1"/>
       <Fourth name="name1" value="value1"/>
    </FirstData>
    <SecondData>
        <Table name="sample" value="value1">
              <First name="name1" value="value1"/>
               <Table name="sample" value="value1">
                 <First name="name1" value="value1"/>

        </Table>
        </Table>
    </SecondData>
```

Here FirstData can have only one line child elements and each child element can have any name but the attributes name and value are mandatory and I need to specify the data types for attributes also. Similarly SecondData but it is recursive. I need to write schema for it in XSD 1.0 only. I tried all options but couldn't get it done. Because element can't be used for restrictions Any help would be highly appreciated. Pls find below the XSD that I tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Generated using Flame-Ware Solutions XML-2-XSD v2.0 at http://www.flame-ware.com/Products/XML-2-XSD/ -->
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">

    <xs:element name="table">
        <xs:complexType>

                <xs:element ref="table" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Note">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="FirstData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>

                            <xs:any id="generic" maxOccurs="unbounded"  processContents="strict" >
                            </xs:any>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="SecondData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="table" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>


</xs:schema>
```

Comment: How many levels deep can the recursion go?

Comment: Can you show the xsd you tried ?

Comment: @Tim, recursion can go as many as it can. no limit on this. but convention is 3 levels

Comment: @Kypaz,  just added FirstData schema because of space issues in comments. <xs:element name="Note">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="FirstData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
       
       <xs:any id="generic" maxOccurs="unbounded"  processContents="strict" >
       </xs:any>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

Comment: @ajit:  Please [edit] your question, add the XSD you've tried, and specify any error messages or XML cases that are not validating per your expectations.   "I tried all options but couldn't get it done" is an unacceptable problem statement.   You have to put some effort into your question to help us help you.  Thanks.

Comment: @ kjhughes, I have added xsd that I tried. regarding adding error messages, my requirement is to add <xsd:any> in FirstData since names can be unpredictable. But using <xsd:any> i am unable to restrict the attributes names and types. This is nothing related to error. I am unable to proceed further since I don't know what else can I add to make the requirement work. please let me know if there is any alternative